# How to store all language character in variable (Perl)?

Tags: perl

I want to store a Swedish word (Brännén) in variable. But I can't store this in variable. How to store this in variable ? Do I need to use any module ?

Comment: Yes you can. What did you try, and what happened when you tried it? (Have you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html yet?)

Comment: Read the link you have been given?

Answer (score 3):

Encode your source code using UTF-8, then use

```
use utf8;                    # Tell Perl source code is encoded using UTF-8
my $var = "Brännén";
```

If you're going to output it, you'll need to encode it.

```
use open ':std', ':locale';  # Tell Perl to decode and encode IO.
print("$var\n");
```

Comment: Could you discuss how the encoding used to create the file affects this? Using a UTF-8 encoded file, I can (seemingly) dispense with both `use` statements, although adding the first requires adding the second as well. This is with a UTF-8 locale as well.

Comment: @chepner, Re "I can (seemingly) dispense with both use statements", Check the length of `$var` and the output of `sprintf("%v04X", $str)`. In one case, `$var` contains UTF-8 bytes. In the other, `$var` contains Unicode code points. Regex and a lot more expect the latter.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. So `use utf8` tells Perl to take the UTF-8 byte sequence actually in the file and create a Unicode string, but without, I'm left with a string with the actual UTF-8 bytes.